# SharePoint CSOM Removesite does not work with modern Team Sites

Tags: sharepoint, csom

The call to CSOM RemoveSite throws an exception when trying to remove sitecollections created with modern Team Sites:

"This site belongs to a office365 group. To remove the site you've to remove the group."

```
SpoOperation removeSiteOperation = tenant.RemoveSite(siteCollectionUrl);
context.Load(tenant);
```

Is there any way to force the deletion, find the group to delete or use a new api?

Answer (score 0):

We can delete the site collections created with modern team sites, we can use PnP PowerShell below to achieve it.

```
$credential = Get-Credential
Connect-PnPOnline https://[tenant].sharepoint.com -credential $credential
Remove-PnPTenantSite https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/ModernTeamSite
```

And deleting the group using the PowerShell below.

```
$credential = Get-Credential
Connect-PnPOnline https://[tenant].sharepoint.com -credential $credential
Remove-PnPUnifiedGroup -Identity groupID // you can get group Ids from Get-PnPUnifiedGroup
```

Reference: [Completely delete an Office365 site collection classic or modern from recycle bin](https://winsmarts.com/completely-delete-an-office365-site-collection-classic-or-modern-from-recycle-bin-ce04808894fa)

And also check the similar thread below.

[Unable to remove Office 365 Group Site Collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231152/unable-to-remove-office-365-group-site-collection)